# tkinter canvas scrolling but scrollbar not adjusting to show canvas size

Tags: python, tkinter

i am trying to place a frame within a canvas with a scroll bar, the canvas scrolls but the scrollbar does not adjust to show the position

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
parent=Tk()
studentFrame=ttk.Frame(parent)
studentFrame.pack()

#settup the canvas
canvas=Canvas(studentFrame,width=700,height=300)
scroller=ttk.Scrollbar(studentFrame, orient=VERTICAL,command=canvas.yview)
canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,stick="nsew")
scroller.grid(row=0,column=1,stick="ns")
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scroller.set)
list=ttk.Frame(canvas,width=700)
ttk.Label(list,text="S/N",width=10,relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=0,column=0,ipadx=3,ipady=3)
ttk.Label(list,text="Name",width=55,relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=0,column=1,ipadx=3,ipady=3)
ttk.Label(list,text="",width=15,relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=0,column=2,ipadx=3,ipady=3)
ttk.Label(list,text="",width=15,relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=0,column=3,ipadx=3,ipady=3)

num=0
r=0
while(r<50):
    num=num+1
    ttk.Label(list,text=num,width=10,relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=r,column=0,ipadx=3,ipady=3)
    ttk.Label(list,text="NAME",width=55,relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=r,column=1,ipadx=3,ipady=3)
    ttk.Label(list,text="EDIT",width=15,relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=r,column=2,ipadx=3,ipady=3)
    ttk.Label(list,text="DELETE",width=15,relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=r,column=3,ipadx=3,ipady=3)
    r=r+1

canvas.create_window((0,0),window=list,anchor=W)
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))
parent.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would help if you modified your code not to depend on a database. A proper [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be able to run out of the box. The fact that the data comes from a database is irrelevant to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the scroll region to be -15 pixels tall (you are setting the bottom-right of the scrollable area to be above the top of the scrollable area)

Comment: how do i fix that

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work i used
    list.update_idletasks()
Before setting the scroll region